# How can I localize the value of CFBundleDisplayName in the Info.plist file?

Tags: iphone, localization

When I look inside the Info.plist file in Xcode, the Property List Editor shows me an value that looks like an variable:

```
${PRODUCT_NAME}
```

How / where can I set up localized names for my app?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a localized file named InfoPlist.strings, containing the name of your application:

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "Name of the App";
```

(Just like Localizable.strings)

Comment: Does the name of that .strings file matter? So I would place the InfoPlist.strings file in every localization-directory like en.lproj, fr.lproj, and so on, right?

Comment: The name matters (and the case too !)

You have to do that for every lproj directory, but you can also do that directly with XCode.

Comment: I ran into a problem with this recently that might affect someone. It is possible to have localized strings in different places in your project directory (think multiple subprojects). If some of the subprojects use the old scheme for lproj like "English.lproj" and other subprojects use the newer scheme "en.lproj" then Xcode will collect those files in different .lproj directories. Then, when the app is on iOS, iOS will use the "English.lproj" directory and not use the files in the "en.lproj" directory, so if your InfoPlist.strings file in "en.lproj" location you'll be out of luck.

Comment: If you need to set it for locales like en_CA to support Canadian English, this approach doesn't work. Seems like this only works for language based localizations...