# How to insert space into a CFBundleDisplayName, IOS

Tags: ios

I'm new to IOS and currently I'm working on Localization of Displaying Apps icon.
and I made InfoPlist.strings

and then I put the text for like this in my InfoPlist.strings(MyLanguage) file

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "sometext&#x2007;sometext&#x2007;andlasttext&#x2007;";
```

and it literally shows every text, include &#x2007 on iphone emulators home screen.

and of course either

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "sometext sometext andlasttext";
```

is also not working! could you help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I localize the value of CFBundleDisplayName in the Info.plist file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737266/how-can-i-localize-the-value-of-cfbundledisplayname-in-the-info-plist-file)

Comment: @fphilipe yes I know but, spacing doesn`t work at all

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me before iOS11`&#x2007;` consider space as double space.
But from iOS 11 Apple has stopped truncating for longer app names. I thing if app name count is greater then 12 to 14, the spaces will be removed. Otherwise, they'll still exist.

```
&#x2007; = 2 spaces
```

Comment: it seems you are right. when I remove some texts and only remain 4-5 characters, it recognize the "space". so there is no way to acheive this at the moment??

Comment: Yes, I think no

Answer (score 0):

Localizing your app display name is actually a very simple task, so let’s just get right into it.

**Set up Localization**

First, make sure you set up localization for another language (Note, this is not all that is required to completely localize an app, just the display name). Select your project in the project navigator, go to Localizations, then select a language to localize your display name.

**Create a Strings File**

Next, you have to create a Strings file that will contain the localized name to be used in your project. Go to File > New > File, select your OS target, go to Resources, and select the Strings file template.

***Select the template, enter InfoPlist into the name field, and create the file.***

**Adding Localized Strings**

Once you have created your strings file, open it and select all of the languages you would like to localize for in the inspector. In your base language file, add the following:

```
/* Localized Bundle Display Name */
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "Your_Localized_Name_In_Native_Language";
```

Then, enter the same in every other language file, swapping in your translated name in the place of your native name as so:

```
/* Localized Bundle Display Name */
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "Localized_Name_In_Other_Language";
```

**When you are done, each file should look like the following:**

[image]

**Add Localization Keys to Info.plist**

The last thing you have to do is add the necessary keys to your Info.plist file to enable your app to read and swap in your localized display name when appropriate. The first key you will add is the “bundle display name” key, it will look like so:

```
Bundle display name = $(PRODUCT_NAME)
```

**You also have to add the “application has localized display name” key and set it to yes, which will look like the following:**

```
Application has localized display name = YES
```

**These keys in Info.plist will look like the following:**

[image]

Thats all there is to it! Your app name will now be displayed in all languages that you localize to.

Comment: I\`m really really thankful @sDev but it doesn`t recognize the space " " too on the home screen